# Magento Retrieve update_time for CMS pages in Magento

Tags: magento

I would like to feed sitemap.xml with CMS update time instead of the date of the day ($date).

In the same way I replaced $date by "Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getId())->getUpdatedAt()" for products.

How to get CMS pages update_time ? With a getModel('cms/page')-> ???

Best regards

Answer (score 5):

Same problem.
Solution:

> substr(Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load($item->getId())->getUpdateTime(),0,10)

Answer (score 0):

...`load($pageId)->getUpdatedAt()`.